# Find the marginal distribution of $Y$ (discrete)?

Tags: probability

We have a random variable $\Lambda$ that is exponentially distributed with the intensity $\lambda = 1$. We are also given that $(Y| \Lambda=u)$~Poisson$(u)$.

We want to find the marginal density distribution of $Y$.

---

I want to do this by finding a pattern for $P[Y=n]$ as we take values for $n$. However, I don't know how to derive this from the conditional distribution. Can someone get me started with $P[Y=1]$? (Assuming this is a valid approach).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $\Lambda\sim\mathcal {Exp}(1)$ and $Y\mid \Lambda ~\sim~\mathcal{Pois}(\Lambda)$

So thus: $$\begin{align}f_\Lambda(u)~= & ~ \mathsf e^{-u}~\mathbf 1_{u\in(0;\infty)} \\[1ex] \mathsf P(Y=n\mid \Lambda=u)~= & ~\dfrac{u^n~\mathsf e^{-u}}{n!}~~\mathbf 1_{n\in\{0,1,2,\ldots\}, u\in(0;\infty)}\\[4ex]\mathsf P(Y=n) ~= & ~ \int\limits_\Bbb R \mathsf P(Y=n\mid \Lambda=u)~f_\Lambda(u)\operatorname d u \\[1ex] = & ~ \dfrac 1{2^{n+1}}\int_0^\infty \dfrac{(2u)^n~\mathsf e^{-2u}}{n!}\operatorname d 2u\quad\mathbf 1_{n\in\{0,1,2,\ldots\}}\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

We have 
$$\Pr(Y=1)=\int_0^\infty \Pr(Y=1\mid \Lambda=u) e^{-u}\,du.$$